# Information retrieval SOTA models

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, information-retrieval

Where can I find sota models of information retrieval? My task is to rank documents by given query by semantic search of embedding. I know that models like ColBERT, SPLADE solve this problem, but I think they are not SOTA now. I tried to find SOTA models on paperswithcode but there almost nothing about this problem.

Comment: The [information retrieval task](https://paperswithcode.com/task/information-retrieval) of [Papers with Code](https://paperswithcode.com/) matches what you described. Why do you think it is not suitable?

Comment: @noe For example, a lot of modern models checked at MTEB benchmark, but there is only one model with MTEB benchmark on paperswithcode

Comment: If you are interested in a specific benchmark like MTEB, you can check [its Huggingface leaderboard](https://huggingface.co/spaces/mteb/leaderboard).

Comment: @noe But what is the difference between text retrieval and information retrieval. My task is just by text query rank documents by relevance. For example, if my query is "horror movies" I just want to rank all movies synopsis and rank "the most horror" movies on the top. As I understand it is text retrieval task but also an information retrieval task

Comment: @noe And also there are not ColBERTV2 or PLAID models on this benchmark on paperswithcode. As I know they are very good models for retrieval